# file_exists() works when executed from phpunit, but not from web page

Tags: php, windows, phpunit, file-exists

I have a file on a network shared location, and I want to check if it exists programmatically with PHP.

When running from PhpUnit, it works fine. My minimal test is:

```
public function testBackupFileExists () {
  $backup_pname = 'R:\myFolder\mySubFolder\myFile.csv';
  $this->assertTrue (file_exists ($backup_pname), "File $backup_pname not found");
}
```

When running from a web interface, from my localhost, [file_exists()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) returns false...

They both use the same version of PHP (7.4.1) and are both executed from the same machine. I also tried running [clearstatcache()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php), but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hasn't safe mode been removed since version 5.4.0? https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode-include-dir

Comment: Ops yes its sorry didnt see that! https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php